# Snowflake Data to OnPrem Tableau? is Data in Transit/Motion Encrypted?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are having reporting applications such as tableau in On-Prem and wanted to use Snowflake for processing the data, When data comes from Snowflake to On-Prem is it encrypted? If not what are the workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by encrypted. Snowflake data is encrypted at rest but when you read it is decrypted (obviously, or it wouldn’t be usable).

If you use a secure connection between Snowflake and your environment then it is encrypted until it reaches you. Whether it stays encrypted in your environment depends on how your environment is configured.

What do you mean by workarounds? Workarounds to what? Are you expecting Tableau to decrypt data on the fly?